# Are there equations that have a solution but cannot be solved any other way than mere guessing?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, $x^x = 3 + 8i$. How are you going to analyse this equation to solve for $x$? Known mathematical functions can’t solve it, I don’t think even bring radicals would solve it.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Lambert W function? I believe that is pretty applicable here if you use the substitution $u = \ln(x), x = e^u.$ In any case you can do better than just guessing, there are numerical methods for finding zeroes

Comment: How could you possibly show that it "cannot be solved any other way than mere guessing".

Comment: Yeah your answer will depend on what branches you use but I think the general solution would be $x = e^{W(\log(3 + 8i))},$ and I found the principal root to be around $x = 2.466 + 0.634i.$

Comment: Good question. Similar to: is there a non-prime number, which cannot be factorized other way then guessing? IMHO it is very easy to create such an equation, just need to be complicated enough to exceed the memory and/or power of potencially  existing computers and algorithms.

Comment: @z100 True, but it is very difficult to predict what will or will not become possible. For instance, with quantum computing there is actually a method which makes the guessing in the prime-factorization problem you mentioned much (MUCH) better educated. (I believe this is called Shor's algorithm?) So I'd be very reluctant to label any such problem "impossible" unless there is some fundamental reason that the problem cannot be solved, such as is the case with the halting problem.

Comment: The halting problem has been solved, with a negative answer.

Comment: No, the halting problem itself is the problem of constructing a Turing machine which can discern whether another Turing machine will halt on a given input. That problem has not been solved, and cannot be solved as proven by Turing. You refer to the question of whether the halting problem is solvable, which has been answered in that it isn't.

Comment: Turing proved there is no general algorithm for determining if any arbitrary program will terminate.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. ${}$

Comment: No problem is unsolvable, if something can’t be solved it is because the axioms we use cannot solve it. An omniscient being could answer the question.

Comment: I've realized my wording hasn't been the most precise, let me rephrase: Turing proved the halting problem for Turing machines is undecidable for Turing machines. So the task of creating a Turing machine which decides the halting problem is provably impossible. (or unsolvable) I agree that there is the possibility of different computing theories being able to solve this problem (in computability theory I believe this is known as a super-Turing Machine and there have been some studies about what it could do) but narrowing it down to constructing a Turing machine it becomes impossible.